# How can I extract the month information from Linux Time Stamp in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, timestamp

In an Excel VBA script I have a Timestamp like this:

```
1402437599000
```

How can I extract the month/year information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, time to answer own question:

```
Dim activityDate As Date
activityDate = 1402437599000
Debug.Print activityDate
Debug.Print Month(activityDate)
```

And you will get:

```
12.07.2014 21:59:59 
7
```

Comment: that `activityDate = 1402437599000` will probably cause an overflow.